# Are there detailed maps of the first Death Star available anywhere?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, map

As a way to make fitness more fun, I'm planning a virtual walk on the Death Star, tracking my distance/steps taken and mapping them out on a map of the Death Star, so that I can, for instance, walk the circumference, or the length of the trench run, or follow Luke's journey through the station from the moment they are pulled in by the tractor beam to the moment they escape. I'd like to track where on the station I am (for instance, when I'm at Detention Block AA-23, etc.)

For this, I'm looking for some (preferably canon) maps of the station, but they're hard to find, and Google seems to mainly return level maps from the *Battlefront* games. Is there a good resource out there to use? I'm willing to do some guesswork, but I'd like to make it as close as possible to canon as I can.

**Are there detailed/canon maps of the first Death Star available anywhere?**

Comment: Not exactly a map, but the images in this post may help give you an idea of what the interior was like: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17462/how-did-the-death-star-move

Comment: Many Botham spies died to bring you the death star plans!

Comment: You might want to ask the Rebel Alliance for a copy of the plans or stop off at Scarif

Comment: *literally anyone talking about running*   "You want to go home and rethink your life"

Comment: "The Death Star plans are not in the main computer."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Star Wars: Death Star Technical Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0874311209) book for West End Games' Star Wars roleplaying game.  Yes, it's for a game - but it's well researched, well written, with plenty of information.  It does include a number of maps of various locations (e.g., the prison complex) within the Death Star.  (You don't need to know how to play the game, or any other rule books, to enjoy this one.)

There are also some comments on the differences between the first and second Death Star.

(I'd be more specific, but I don't think I've opened my copy since 1994...)

Answer (score 4):

You can get a [Haynes Manual for The Death Star](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Death-Star-Manual-Orbital-Workshop/dp/0857333720).

I've never read the book so can't say how good it is or whether it'll meet your needs (if it doesn't you'll need to use The Force to find one that does).

Comment: It's not especially detailed in terms of granular maps.

Comment: @Valorum That's because Chilton and Haynes manuals are kind of worthless. The information they contain can easily be found on the internet and in any case isn't detailed enough to be worth paying for. What you want is the Death Star Factory Service Manual